How to load an image from MAUI ImageSource?
I'm new to .NET MAUI.
I'm trying to load an image from an ImageSource.
I thought it would be a simple thing, after all, we're dealing with an image source.
Silly me.
Anyway, I'm searching high and low and all I can't seem to find any platform-independent way to load an image.
What I want to do is simply get the binary data from the image.
Edited for clarification:

What I'm trying to do is to through an ImageSource get an image so I can apply some modifications to that image and “ship” it away as another ImageSource.
In effect I want to replace one ImageSource for another, delivering a slightly altered image. Think like applying an overlay, but straight to the image.
This is for a control I'm planning.
Edited for clarification II:

Imagine you have a control like this:
<ctrl:MyControl
    Source="{Binding WhateverImageSource}">
</ctrl:MyControl>

Now, because this is a control, it can have a disabled state. To visually represent this state, I want to display the image with an alpha channel 50% transparent.
I get the binary of the image, apply the transformation, and return it as a new ImageSource.
[rant]
I don't know who designed this or what was the motivation behind the need to over-engineer everything, but, in my naïveté, I would have designed it a little bit different.
But what do I know?
[/rant]

Hi @aulo Santos, you want to load image from an external source?

At which step did you encounter the issue? Was it in obtaining the ImageSource, or in converting the ImageSource into an Image control/image file?

Is there a reason why you can't use Opacity property?
Alternativly, you could also overlay a second image on top the first with opacity baked in, or set the opacity of the second image.
